# Auto-Complete Association with Nested Attributes and Many to Many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've followed the Auto-Complete Association Railscast to add 'Artists' to my 'Releases'. Everything appeared to be working nicely, but I then noticed it's creating a new artist everytime, instead of using an existing artist if selected via the autocomplete.

Unlike the railscast, i'm using a many to many relationship and artists are also accepted as a nested attribute under releases, so i'm aware the issue is probably related to either or both of those.

Below are my models and relevant views. It seems to me that the line `self.artist = Artist.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?` isn't being used. I thought this was because I have `f.autocomplete_field :name` instead of `f.autocomplete_field :artist_name` but when I change to that I get a no method error!

Can anyone help please?

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_releases

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist_releases

  def artist_name
   artist.try(:name)
  end

  def artist_name=(name)
   self.artist = Artist.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
  end      
end

class ArtistRelease < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :release
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :releases, :through => :artist_releases  
end


#Release Form
<%= form_for(@release) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title, :class => "text" %>
    <%= f.fields_for :artists do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'artist_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Artist", f, :artists %> </p>
<% end %>

#Artist Fields
<p>
<%= f.label :artist_name, "Artist" %><br />
<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_artist_name_releases_path, :id_element => '#artist_id', :class => "text" %>
</p>
```

Comment: I also notice :id_element => '#artist_id', what was that supposed to be for?

Comment: I was trying to pass the id to the join table....but clearly that didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

you should either put

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :artist_name, autocomplete_artist_name_releases_path, :class => "text" %>
```

where f is the release form. but this assigns to Release#artist (only one), which should be undefined, since your release model `has_many :artists`

what you could do is allow many names in comma separated list. Note we put this directly in release form, no nested attributes needed.

```
#Release Form
<%= form_for(@release) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title, :class => "text" %>
...
<%= f.autocomplete_field :artist_names, autocomplete_artist_name_releases_path, :class => "text", 'data-delimiter' => ',' %>
<% end %>
```

in release model, no nested attributes needed.

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_releases

  attr_accessor :artist_names 
  def artist_names=(names)
    self.artists = names.split(',').map { |name| Artist.find_or_create_by_name(name.strip) }
  end 
end
```

you can solve with nested attributes, but only recommend if you have multiple fields for artists to fill in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give this a go and report back.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method `artist_names'` when I try your suggestion to allow many names. Any idea why?

Comment: also, you need to split on comma and best strip names.

Comment: Hmmm, still can't get this to work, but i've also just realised that I do actually need seperate fields for each artist as I eventually want to add an additional field/select menu to specify if the artist is primary or featuring.

Comment: please specify what error you getting and where. if you want nested ttributes, that could probably be another question

Comment: It's the undefined method artist_names error again. Nested attributes actually works well, expect for the fact that each artist added, even if from autocomplete creates a new entry in artists table.

Comment: ok, you misunderstood, you can put f.autocomplete field to release form (no nesting needed). see my update. now if you do want nested forms and run into a problem, please ask another question :) thx

Comment: did you solve this? if you use nested forms you need to send id hidden field, which you set on autocompletion with :id_element => '#artist_id, make sure put the correct input tag id. this way if id exists, no new artist will be created, but will just be updated/associated.  let us know